# How do I get the number of passwords I want to properly display instead of showing too many passwords?

Tags: java

```
 import java.util.Scanner;
 import java.io.File;
 import java.io.FileWriter;
 import java.io.IOException;


 public class Main
 {
 public static void main(String[] args) {
     try {
         //Introduce Program
        // System.out.println("**********************************************************");
         //System.out.println("Welcome to a simple password generator.");
         //System.out.println("The password will include lowercase, uppercase, & numbers.");
     
         File file = new File("passcode.txt");
         if (!file.exists()) {
             file.createNewFile();
         }

         
             while(true) {
                 Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
                 System.out.print("\nEnter a password length (6 or more): ");
                 int length = input.nextInt();
             
                 if(length < 6) {
                     System.out.println("\n  Password length too short. Please try again.");
                 } else {
                     String randomPassword = "";
                             for(int j = 0; j < length; j++) {
                                     randomPassword += randomCharacter();
                             }

                             FileWriter fw = new FileWriter("passcode.txt", true);
                             fw.write(randomPassword);
                             fw.write("\n");
                             fw.close();
                         
                     System.out.println("\nA password has been sent to text file");
                     System.out.print("Would you like to generate another password?  Y/N ");
                     char choice = input.next().charAt(0);
                 
                     if(choice == 'n') {
                         System.out.println("\nThank you for using the Pass CodeGenerator.\n");
                         System.out.print("Here are your randomly generated codes:");
                         

                         **int count = 0;
                         Scanner myReader = new Scanner(file);
                         while (myReader.hasNextLine()) {
                             count += 1;
                             String data = myReader.nextLine();
                             System.out.format("\n%d.  %s", count, data);**

                         }
                         myReader.close();
                         
                         break;
                     } else if(choice == 'y') {
                         continue;
                     }
                 }
             }
     } catch (IOException e) {
         System.out.println("An error occurred.");
         e.printStackTrace();
     }
 }

 
 public static char randomCharacter() {
             int rand = (int)(Math.random()*62);
             //0-61 inclusive = all possible values of rand
             //0-9 inclusive = 10 possible numbers/digits
             //10-35 inclusive = 26 possible uppercase letters
             //36-61 inclusive = 26 possible lowercase letters
             //If rand is between 0 (inclusive) and 9 (inclusive), then it's a number/digit
             //If rand is between 10 (inclusive) and 35 (inclusive), then it's an uppercase letter
             //If rand is between 36 (inclusive) and 61 (inclusive), then it's a lowercase letter

             **if(rand <= 9) {
                     int number = rand + 48;
                     return (char)(number);
             } else if(rand <= 35) {
                     int uppercase = rand + 55;
                     return (char)(uppercase);
             } else {
                     int lowercase = rand + 61;
                     return (char)(lowercase);**
             }
     } }
```

So if I picked to do 3 passwords, 1 with 8 letters, one with 6, and one with 7, it prints out this.

```
Thank you for using the Pass Code Generator.

Here are your randomly generated codes:
1.  EY0ZSJq
2.  VmJxglEp
3.  bily6wxBX4
4.  L2MvxzHx
5.  lLPAQC
6.  CtnlU4
7.  CB7z1ZIc
8.  XIIm71ILe
9.  JGmc79
10.  ElwRG8Tf
11.  13DJFi
12.  loCZlIQ
13.  oY7JhlHy
14.  VmqD00
15.  47HQf3GT
16.  lNvR6z
17.  nM45JvA
18.  eXs0vkcP9
19.  UO6G6sCQ
20.  MrOsjvaZ
21.  Gr028GvMM
22.  cxBK6x
23.  JSgXn6k9
24.  A4miDf
25.  oCeS54o
```

Comment: Java and JavaScript are different languages.

Comment: please format your code correctly, noone wants to read your unreadable formatted code

Comment: Why did you edit the tag from `java` back to `javascript`?  This is not javascript

Comment: So what is the problem?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

Your code runs fine.

I think the problem is, that you executed your code multiple times and the Strings are written to the same file.

When you create 3 passwords one the first run, there are 3 lines in the file.
When you create 3 passwords in a second run, it adds 3 lines, and there are 6 lines in the file.

- 3 generations -> 3 lines in file
- 3 generations -> 6 lines in file (3 from first run)

What you can do is, to delete the file at the beginning like this:

```java
 File file = new File("passcode.txt");
 if (!file.exists()) {
   file.createNewFile();
 } else {
   file.delete();
 }
```

Be aware that the generated Strings from the first run get lost here.